# Resolver position offset

Tags: motor, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I try to control the BLDC motor. I am using the Resolver sensor to get the position of the motor position. but I don't know how can I get the rotor offset position.

Can someone explain it to me?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one method:

1. If you are running six-step, the best approach is to run the motor with your controller and enter different offsets until the phase signals are symmetrical trapezoids.
2. If you are running sinusoidal, you can apply direct current to two of the motor phases.  The rotor will rotate to a position where your "Q" vector is zero (obviously there is no torque here, so the rotor field is aligned with the stator field).
3. You can spin the motor shaft using another motor and compare the back emf from the phases to the resolver output.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. 

I will try method 2 you gave me.

I run Sinusoidal. I have tried to get the offset value. 

step 1:  I set any rotor offset value and then run the motor.

step 2: I measure the phase-to-phase voltage waveform and resolver angle (0-360 degrees)
step 3: if the 0-degree resolver and the phase-to-phase voltage are -V amplitude.  so the offset is correct.  if it isn't, then the difference between the resolver phase with phase-to-phase voltage is the rotor offset
after doing 3 steps I still can't find out rotor offset.

What do you think about my method?